# Why is there an $i$ in the definition of hadronic decay constants?

Tags: quantum-field-theory, particle-physics, conventions, complex-numbers, matrix-elements

The decay of (for example) a pion can be parameterized by a decay constant $f_\pi$ defined via
$$ \langle 0 | \bar d \gamma_\mu \gamma^5 u |\pi^+(p) \rangle = i f_\pi p_\mu $$ $$ f_\pi \approx 131 \text{ MeV.}$$
My question is **why do we include the $i$ on the RHS?** In other words how do we know that the matrix element on the LHS is purely imaginary?

Comment: it is a convention; you can reabsorb whatever phase you want into $|\pi^+(p)\rangle$.

Answer (score 2):

Well, you may define your conventions, and physicists are perverse enough to actually do that (watch them...), any way you want. This is the dominant convention, and the logical ["chain of custody"](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/547195/derivation-of-pcac-condition-langle-0j5-mu-ax-pi-bp-rangle-if-pi), so to speak, is, schematically,
$$
\pi^+\mapsto \pi^+ + f_\pi \theta^+, \qquad \leadsto \\
J_{5}^{\mu~~+} = \frac{δ{\mathcal L}}{δ\partial_\mu \pi^+}  \frac{δ\pi^+}{δ\theta^+}=f_\pi \partial^\mu \pi^+ ~~~(\sim -\bar d \gamma^\mu \gamma^5 u  ),~~~\leadsto \\  
\langle 0 | \bar d \gamma_\mu \gamma^5 u |\pi^+(p) \rangle = i f_\pi p_\mu ~.
$$
I've been cavalier/dyslexic with signs and factors, but this is the choice for a real weak iso-raising matrix $\tau^+$. So the *i* pops up in the conversion from *p* to -*i*∂ . For the neutral pion (hermitean), you'd get a hermitean current, which is the standard convention.