Effective Lagrangian for neutral pion to photons
How would I write the effective Lagrangian in the lowest order perturbation theory for the (standard model tree-level prohibited) process $$\pi^0\rightarrow 2\gamma?$$ My first guess would be something like $$L=L_{\mbox{free scalar}}+L_{\mbox{free photons}}+g\phi A^\mu A_\mu.$$ Where the free scalar field has mass $m=m_\pi$ and the free photons have ~$F_{\mu\nu}F^{\mu\nu}$. I don't think the above effective lagrangian respects gauge invariance, so I instead write $$L=L_{\mbox{free scalar}}+L_{\mbox{free photons}}+g\phi F^{\mu\nu} F_{\mu\nu},$$ where $g$ has mass dimension $-1$. Is this the correct approach to effective Lagrangians? If this is correct, then would my Feynman rules be vertices with $(-ig)$ and external photon polarizations $\epsilon^*$ analogous to QED?

The decay $\pi^0 \to \gamma \gamma$ is the dominant decay mode of the neutral pion and, of course, not prohibited in the standard model. For more details, search for "chiral anomaly", e.g. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chiral_anomaly

I'll edit it to say prohibited at tree level lowest order perturbation theory. My question still remains.

See https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/554221

I understand the process requires a fermion loop diagram. That is not my question. My question is if I wanted to construct an effective Lagrangian that couples the scalar to two photons in lowest order of perturbation (tree level), how do i do that?

You find the explicit and correct expression for the effective Lagrangian in the the article by Comas Zachos quoted in my previous comment.  Your proposed form of the effective Lagrangian is wrong as it ignores the fact that the pion is a pseudoscalar.

The pion is a pseudo scalar, and the term given in the linked question conserves parity as it should. You are interested in the strength of the effective coupling in first principles?

That's right. The goal would be to write down some kind of effective Lagrangian, and find the coupling strength given the experimental lifetime.

The effective lagrangian provided in the link is accurate and correct.

This question is similar to: Axial anomaly at the level of particles. If you believe it’s different, please [edit] the question, make it clear how it’s different and/or how the answers on that question are not helpful for your problem.
